# Annoying USB Random Noises

Tags: usb, connection, webcam

I just added a new battery to my laptop today, and a new webcam. Then suddenly about maybe 12 hours after it starts making the USB sound when you insert and remove it. It plays the 'IN' sound then the 'OUT' sound and then plays them both together at the same time, then a little pause, then it continues the loop. Please help me :( Especially this is on Christmas.

Comment: Sounds like a communication issue with the webcam. Can you provide some event log entries relevant to this?

Comment: If you have other things plugged in the USB , try this new item with the other things removed, if you are using a hub, make sure you power a hub when devices on the hub would need to be powered with a good quallity adapter for power.  If all else fails via just the laptops own USb, try a powered hub item, for the devices that want to be powered by the USB, like small hard drives, cameras , and charging stuff.